MIME Type Issue with React App Served by Kubernetes NGINX Ingress
When I access to my react web app I got a blank page with thus errors in console:
Warning: The script at “https://www.example.net/beta/static/js/main.6e6f64a2.js” has been loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

I create an app using create-react-app and yarn and with this kind of architecture :
.  
├── CREATE_REACT_APP_README.md  
├── Dockerfile  
├── README.md  
├── node_modules 
├── package.json  
├── public  
├── src  
└── yarn.lock  

I containerised it with docker and this Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

RUN yarn global add serve

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3000"]


I deploy it on my Kubernetes (microk8s) cluster using a deployment and a service.
Deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: new-portfolio
  name: new-portfolio
  namespace: portfolio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: new-portfolio
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: new-portfolio
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: My_username/my_app
        name: new-portfolio

Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: new-portfolio-service
  namespace: portfolio
spec:
  selector:
    app: new-portfolio
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000

I want my app to be accessible at www.example.net/beta so I added an entry to my ingress.yaml config file that look like that.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: personal-website-ingress
  namespace: portfolio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - www.example.net
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
  - host: www.example.net
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/beta"
        backend:
          service:
            name: new-portfolio-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: personal-website-service
            port:
              number: 80

Then I add this entry to my package.json file in my react app:
  "homepage": "/beta",

I deploy all of that, I am able to access to example.net that show my my first web app but when I go to example.net/beta I have a blank page, with errors mentioned previously, in the browser console:
Warning: The script at “https://www.example.net/beta/static/js/main.6e6f64a2.js” has been loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

I firstly try to check logs of ingress and react app:
Ingress:
X.X.X.X - - [07/Sep/2024:16:48:39 +0000] "GET /beta/ HTTP/2.0" 200 787 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0" 347 0.002 [portfolio-new-portfolio-service-80] [] 10.1.73.84:3000 787 0.002 200 2124b505a239c98bca47093ecc8c0be2
X.X.X.X - - [07/Sep/2024:16:48:39 +0000] "GET /beta/static/js/main.6e6f64a2.js HTTP/2.0" 200 787 "https://www.example.net/beta/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0" 90 0.002 [portfolio-new-portfolio-service-80] [] 10.1.73.84:3000 787 0.002 200 78240db2eae116497cb010fd564d4da5

That suggest the file is well get
Pod with react app:
 HTTP  9/7/2024 4:51:36 PM 10.1.73.70 GET /
 HTTP  9/7/2024 4:51:36 PM 10.1.73.70 Returned 200 in 1 ms
 HTTP  9/7/2024 4:51:36 PM 10.1.73.70 GET /
 HTTP  9/7/2024 4:51:36 PM 10.1.73.70 Returned 200 in 1 ms

So the file is well served to my browser but with the wrong MIME type.
This issue is link to the /beta redirection because if I deploy my app to the root of my domain, basically www.example.net, it works well.
I try to change some things on the rewrite-target field but the problem is same.
